# Cannot load data.table package in MRS remote session

Tags: r, package, microsoft-r, deployr, rro

When I try to load data.table package in a remote session on a MS R Server, I get an error:

```
REMOTE> library(data.table)
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'data.table'
```

Using the namespace directly I get more colour:

```
REMOTE> data.table::data.table(x = 1)
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'data.table', details:
  call: assign("cbind.data.frame", tt, envir = asNamespace("base"), inherits = FALSE)
  error: cannot change value of locked binding for 'cbind.data.frame'
```

Any advice on how to resolve this?

Here some more information about the way R server is set up and how I install packages:

1. R server runs on a separate machine (call it A) from the one where I start the remote session. The machine A is configured as one-box i.e. the web-node and compute-node both run on that machine.
2. I am running the R client on my local machine (call it B) via Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3, Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01038 with R Tools for Visual Studio, 1.0.30228.1316 RC2.
3. I installed data.table package directly on the machine A by running 'Rgui' console with this command: install.packages('data.table'). The library installs into lib C:\RglobalPkgs specified by R_LIBS system environment variable on the machine A.
4. I create a remote session on the machine B running these commands:

   `library(mrsdeploy)
    remoteLogin("http://machineA:12800",
                   username = "admin",
                   password = "xyz",
                   session = TRUE,
                   commandline = TRUE)`
5. In the remote session I try to load the data.table package as described above at the beginning of my question which fails. Running .libPath() in the remote session gives:

   `REMOTE> .libPaths()
   [1] "C:/RglobalPkgs"
   [2] "C:/Program Files/Microsoft/R Server/R_SERVER/library"`

Comment: Is this on a local machine?

Comment: @HongOoi the OP already mentioned it's a remote session on R Server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos mrsdeploy supports a basic one-box config, where everything runs on your own machine. In this case, it's possible for the local and remote sessions to share packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed the dev team about this. Response below:

> We're aware of the issue and will push a fix in the next release. 
>   A workaround is to go to C:\Program Files\Microsoft\R Server\R_SERVER\deployr\RServe\RScripts\source.R on the machine with the compute node and comment out
>
> ```
> #  unlockBinding("unlockBinding",b)
> #  assign("unlockBinding", deployr.unlock, envir=b)
> #  lockBinding("unlockBinding", b)
> ```
>
> Then go to services and restart the RServe9.0.0 service.

Comment: Thanks for replies. I am not running a one-box configuration. R server is on a separate machine. The error occurs whether I install data.table on the server machine or in the remote session.

Comment: Use `library (*, lib.loc=path)` to point R to where you installed data.table

Comment: I did that: library(data.table, lib.loc = "C:/RglobalPkgs"). Still the same error. It does not seem to be the problem of R not finding the package. It fails while loading it.

Comment: You should put all that in the question, including how you installed data.table.

Comment: Done. See my question above. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: R_LIBS is a system variable. I put the result of running .libPath() within the remote session on the machine B in my original question.

Comment: Try running `install.packages` from within the remote session. It may not have permission to read/write to that directory.

Comment: install.packages('data.table') from the remote session runs successfully but when I subsequently do library(data.table) I get the same error as in my original question.

Comment: Okay, I can reproduce this on my own machine. Looks like an unexpected interaction between mrsdeploy and data.table. I'll notify the dev team.

Comment: 30-minute turnaround time on the email!